# What's this concept called in Python or any programming language?

Tags: python

- *code1*

  ```
  if name.lower().endswith('b') and len(name) > 2
  ```

Suppose name is a type `string` like `name = "test_string"`

So the `name.lower().endswith('b')` is similar to `name.lower() and endswith('b')`,

like then the alternate code of *code1* will be:

- *code2*

  ```
  if name.lower() and name.endswith('b') and len(name) > 2
  ```

Are *code1* and *code2* the same?.

The doubt is what's the significance of *code1*? What's that nested "`.`"? I really don't know. Is it like some sort of accessing technical feature in Python or any other programming language?

If so, which languages offer this concept?...

Comment: They're not the same. `name.lower()` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the string in `name`.

Comment: This is called method chaining. The result of `name.lower()` is then used to call `endswith()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is called method chaining.

```
x.method1().method2().method3()
```

is equivalent to

```
temp1 = x.method1()
temp2 = temp1.method2()
temp2.method3()
```

So

```
if name.lower().endswith('b') and len(name) > 2:
```

is equivalent to:

```
lowername = name.lower()
if lowername.endswith('b') and len(name) > 2:
```

It's not equivalent to

```
if name.lower() and name.endswith('b') and len(name) > 2:
```

because `name.lower()` doesn't modify `name`. So when you call `name.endswith('b')`, `name` still contains the original value, which could be uppercase.

If the value were a mutable type, the method *could* update it in place and return it. However, the general Python convention is that methods either update in place or they return a new object, they don't do both. That's why `list.append()` returns `None`, not the updated list, for instance. (Some functions update in place and then return a related value, e.g. `list.pop()` removes an element from the list and returns the element.)

Comment: IS this the same thing in any OOPS language suppose Java?..

Comment: Yes. Although in some languages it's common to use "fluent interfaces" where the updater methods also return the object, so you can use chaining to make multiple changes to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an example:

```py
name = "StackOverFLOW"

# Code 1
if name.lower().endswith('w'):
    print("Passed Code 1")

# Code 2
if name.lower() and name.endswith('w'):
    print("Passed Code 2")
```

The output for the above code is:

```sh
Passed Code 1
```

The reason for it can explain your query of using a period (.) in python which is more or less similar to the usage in other languages.

In Code 1, the `name.lower()` returns `stackoverflow`, and then it is again passed through a string method `endswith('w')` which turns out to be True.

In Code 2, the `name.lower()` returns `stackoverflow` same as Code 1 but it is not passed through the `endswith('w')` method. Instead there is another condition `name.endswith('w')` which check if `name` i.e. `StackOverFLOW` ends with a lower case `w` which is `False` and hence, the condition breaks.